# Protect Javascript library from JS errors on page

Tags: javascript

I have written a JavaScript library that gets consumed by a web page on a different domain. The JavaScript file I have created is an SDK which other parties consume, call in to and return data to the consuming web page. The consumer will treat the SDK I write as a 3rd party integration.

I want to ensure when I write my library that any Javascript errors in the consuming web page does not impact on my library. Is there a way I can achieve this level of protection?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. What kind of errors, and how do you see that impacting your library?

Comment: Any errors - any errors that would stop my library from executing its JS.

Comment: And why would that be a problem for you? By all means avoid errors in your own library, but if the app of the person trying to consume your library errors out, then how is that going to impact you? They're not going to be using your library, because their app has errors.

Comment: Your library is fully isolated by default. All error handling should be written though, but only for your own logic.